# Angle in ellipse coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need an explanation here. Consider the MWE below. If I set `X=Y=3` the point `(-20:{\X} and \Y)` ends up at the `-20` angle as expected. If I set `Y=1` then the point is on the ellipse, but at a different angle. Exactly how is `(ang:X and Y)` interpreted when `X` is not equal to `Y`? Where is that angle measured against?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\X{3}
  \def\Y{1}
  \draw (0,0) circle ({\X} and \Y);
  \fill[red,opacity=0.5] (-20:{\X} and \Y) circle (3pt);
  \draw (0,0) --  (4,0) arc (0:-20:4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An ellipse is basically a "squashed circle". The angle refers to the unsquashed circle. Try `\def\X{3}
  \def\Y{1}
  \def\angle{-60}
  \draw (0,0) circle ({\X} and \Y);
  \fill[red] (\angle:{\X} and \Y) circle (2pt);
  \draw (0,0) --  (3,0) arc (0:\angle:3) -- cycle;
  \draw (\angle:3) -- +(0,3);` to see this

Comment: How very annoying. That makes ellipse segments in specific delta angles so much harder to make

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(angle:a and b)` is equal to `({cos(angle)*a},{sin(angle)*b})`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\X{3cm}
  \def\Y{1cm}
  \draw (0,0) circle ({\X} and \Y);
  \fill[red,opacity=0.5] (-20:{\X} and \Y) circle (3pt);
  \fill[blue] ({cos(-20)*\X},{sin(-20)*\Y}) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for reference for others coming by, an item on an ellipse, centred at origin having angle A to the x-axis is made from the angle given by ` \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleB}{atan((\X/\Y)*tan(\angle))}`, should I add this you your answer?

Comment: You can draw the -20 degree point on the ellipse by `\fill[red] (-20:{\X*\Y/sqrt((cos(-20)*\Y)^2+(sin(-20)*\X)^2)}) circle (2pt);`

Comment: @StefanH that would probably be easier

Comment: @StefanH however my calculation gives you the angle that can be fed into `arc` to give a part of the ellipse arc